# Including image width and height when using the rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

When using the rails asset pipeline, for example `image_tag "logo.png"` leads to the following HTML:

```
<img src="/assets/logo-0c1cd0fb.png">
```

Is it possible for rails to **detect the image dimensions (width and height) automatically**, so that it generates an HTML including dimensions for faster page rendering, like this:

```
<img src="/assets/logo-0c1cd0fb.png" width="230" height="32">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably need half size for retina images I would like to improve @iblue's answer. I changed some lines to achieve this easier. You need [fastimage gem](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage) & put the following code in ApplicationHelper.

```
  def retina_image_tag(source, options = {})
    if !options[:size] # Do not overwrite size if already set by caller
      @@image_size ||= {} # Cache for image sizes
      if !@@image_size[source] # Fill cache
        @@image_size[source] = FastImage.size(::Rails.root.to_s+"/app/assets/images/#{source}", :raise_on_failure => true)
        @@image_size[source] = [@@image_size[source][0]/2, @@image_size[source][1]/2]
      end
      options = options.merge(:style => "max-width:" + @@image_size[source][0].to_s + "px")
    end
    image_tag(source, options)
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Thomas I came up with this (requires `gem "fastimage"` in your `Gemfile`)

```
def image_tag(source, options = {})
  if !options[:size] # Do not overwrite size if already set by caller
    @@image_size ||= {} # Cache for image sizes
    if !@@image_size[source] # Fill cache
      @@image_size[source] = FastImage.size(::Rails.root.to_s+"/app/assets/images/#{source}", :raise_on_failure => true).join("x")
    end
    options = options.merge(:size => @@image_size[source])
  end
  super(source, options)
end
```

Just add to your `ApplicationHelper`

Answer (score 3):

Use https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage and then pass it to image_tag

Answer (score 1):

To include the image dimensions automatically you can use [dimensions-rails](https://github.com/elia/dimensions-rails).

You can also use the [dimensions gem](https://github.com/sstephenson/dimensions) (requires `gem "dimensions"`) to render retina image tags.

```
def retina_image_tag(source, options = {})
  unless options[:size] or options[:width] or options[:height]
    fs_path = ::Rails.application.assets.find_asset(source)
    fs_path = fs_path.present? ? fs_path.pathname : File.join(::Rails.public_path, source)

    if fs_path.present? and File.exist? fs_path
      options[:width], options[:height] = ::Dimensions.dimensions(fs_path).map do |x| x/2 end
    end
  end

  image_tag(source, options)
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
image_tag("logo.png", :size => "230x32")
```

should do it

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change this manually on every page the image is used when I change images. Rails should detect the image size automatically.